# Docker images. How to delete them safely

Tags: docker

I have several docker images in my ubuntu pc that are taking a lot of space.
I want to delete them except the one I am currently using.

However, other than the images I can clearly identify (by their names and tags) there are other images that I suppose were created in the intermediate process of creating the images. They are also listed in `docker images`

Since I am still using one of the images (I run it from time to time) I am a bit afraid of erasing some unidentified image that might have some relation

How do I delete docker images that I am not using safely?(including intermediate ones)

(just in case I know that `docker rmi` is used to delete images. That is not the matter of this question)

Comment: `docker image prune` maybe ? See the doc : https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

Comment: There shouldn't be any risk of deleting an image that's not attached to a running container, since you should be able to `docker pull` it from a registry or `docker build` it from source.  `docker run` will automatically pull the image if it's not present locally.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. One question, what happens if the image is running at the moment and I delete one of the associated images? I can understand there will be a `docker pull` when running the image, but what if it is already running?

Comment: `docker rmi` will fail with an error message.